# Sum of 2 rows using CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to display the SUM of **Subscriptional** row and showed as one **Subscriptional**. My script showed below:

[image]

```
DECLARE @DATENOW datetime
SET @DATENOW = Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
use ews
Select CASE
    WHEN ot.PaymentType=0 
    THEN 'Transactional - '
    ELSE 'Subscriptional - '
    End as 'Payment Type',
          count (distinct o.OrderNumber) as 'Count' from    [order] AS o WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN
      OrderProducts AS op WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderNumber = op.OrderNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN
      OrderTransaction AS ot WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderNumber = ot.OrderNumber
    where  o.Datecreated >=DATEADD(D,-1,@DATENOW ) 
    AND o.Datecreated <=DATEADD(ms,-3,@DATENOW )
    AND o.status not like'%Deleted%'
    group  by ot.PaymentType
    UNION
     SELECT 'Deleted', count(*)
     from   [order] AS o WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    OrderProducts AS op WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderNumber = op.OrderNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    OrderTransaction AS ot WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderNumber = ot.OrderNumber
                   where  o.Datecreated >=DATEADD(D,-1,@DATENOW ) 
    AND o.Datecreated <=DATEADD(ms,-3,@DATENOW )
    and o.status like'%Deleted%'
     group  by ot.paymenttype
```

[image]

Here's the raw result, it showed that the Transactional STD and WB summed up on the 2nd result, but the Subscriptional SCR and SSR didn't. I'm looking to summed both Subscriptional SSR and SCR on the 2nd result to.

*i.e*
Subscriptional - 6
Transactional - 26

Answer (score 0):

I change the original query into subquery and move the group by on after subquery. Fix the sum of  column CountOrder.

```
SELECT [Payment Type], SUM([CountOrder]) FROM (
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ot.paymenttype = 0 THEN 'Transactional - ' 
         ELSE 'Subscriptional - ' 
       END                            AS [Payment Type], 
       Count (DISTINCT o.ordernumber) AS [CountOrder]
FROM   [order] AS o WITH (nolock) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orderproducts AS op WITH (nolock) 
                    ON o.ordernumber = op.ordernumber 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertransaction AS ot WITH (nolock) 
                    ON o.ordernumber = ot.ordernumber 
WHERE  o.datecreated >= Dateadd(d, -1, @DATENOW) 
       AND o.datecreated <= Dateadd(ms, -3, @DATENOW) 
       AND o.status NOT LIKE'%Deleted%' 
UNION 
SELECT 'Deleted' AS [Payment Type], 
       Count(*) AS [CountOrder]
FROM   [order] AS o WITH (nolock) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orderproducts AS op WITH (nolock) 
                    ON o.ordernumber = op.ordernumber 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertransaction AS ot WITH (nolock) 
                    ON o.ordernumber = ot.ordernumber 
WHERE  o.datecreated >= Dateadd(d, -1, @DATENOW) 
       AND o.datecreated <= Dateadd(ms, -3, @DATENOW) 
       AND o.status LIKE'%Deleted%' 
       )

GROUP BY [Payment Type]
```

Comment: im getting same result

Comment: I appreciate your help pal, but im still getting same result :'(

Comment: This should return Error because column [CountOrder] is not aggregated, Are you sure you are running it correctly? Try to run it in SQL server management studio so you can eliminate another factor for error.

Comment: I fix it and you can try again

Answer (score 0):

In your second `SELECT` block, instead of `count(*)` use `count(o.OrderNumber)` and check.

Comment: I appreciate your help pal, but im still getting same result.

Comment: If you wan to get the sum, shouldn't there be a `sum()` somewhere?  Just check if `sum(count(distinct o.ordernumber))` works.